# Load images from a different domain with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Can I load images from a different domain with an htaccess file?

So if my HTML as this:

```
<img src="www.site.com/img" />
```

Can I make it be as if the HTML was:

```
<img src="www.site2.com/img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible of course, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) you can find the documentation of the html element img.

In your example it should state this:

```
<img src="http://www.site2.com/img" />
```

Please note, that you need to add the protocol of your remote domain to make this work properly.